# Application found in unity dash, but .desktop file not found in /usr/share/applications

Tags: unity-dash

I currently have an application, in this case `hyper.app`, but it's `.desktop` isn't found in `/usrs/share/applications/`.  Is there another place I could try to find this.  I tried `find / -name "hyper.app"`, `find / -name ".desktop"` and a few others, but to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to find said `.desktop` file?

Comment: was it installed from with `apt`, or a `.deb` package? You may have to create one yourself.

Comment: Is this Hyper , the webkit terminal, that you're talking about ?

Comment: It is.  I had two copies of the shortcut in dash, one from a `deb` file and a second pointing to a compiled version in `~/Documents`.  I removed the `.deb` installation easily enough, and deleted the compiled version, but there's still a shortcut to `hyper.app` in unity-dash, with no corresponding `.desktop` file in `/u/s/applications`

Comment: `:|` I just found out about `~/.local/share/applications`.  Embarrassment ensues.  The `.desktop` file was in there.

Comment: I've downloaded and extracted the deb package for Hyper. It's supposed to have placed the file into `/usr/share/applications/Hyper.desktop`. Whatever reason was for the file to be misplaced, glad you found it :)